# Using Javascript array to produce a bubble chart (D3js)

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use the D3js Bubble chart example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) however the example is based around using a CSV file for the data.

How would I modify the example to use a JavaScript array instead of the CSV file?

```
d3.csv("flare.csv", function(d) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSV example you link to, part of the code is carried out inside the callback function of the `d3.csv` function. In other words, we have to wait until the data has loaded in order to use it.

However, if you already have the data in an array, then you can use it immediately. I've shown below the start of the program (note: not complete):

```
/* The data doesn't have to be loaded and can be used immediately */
var classes = [
    { id: 'flare', value: 0 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics', value: 0 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics.cluster', value: 0 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster', value: 3938 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure', 3812 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster', 6714 },
    { id: 'flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge', 743 }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(1.5);

/*
    This code was inside the d3.csv() callback in the original example,
    because we had to wait for the data to be loaded from the csv 
    to become available.

    But as we already have the data in memory in the array,
    it can be executed immediately (see the classes array
    being used).
*/
var root = d3.hierarchy({ children: classes })
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
            var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
            d.id = id;
            d.package = id.slice(0, i);
            d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
    });

//Carry on with rest of script as per the blocks example
```